# Angular2 http error response status

Tags: error-handling, typescript, angular

I'm trying to handle specific response codes in my Angular2 app. I have this code:

```
handleError(res: Response) {
  console.log('Response status is %d', res.status);
  if (res.status === 403) {
    logUserOut();
  }
}
```

The log statement there prints out `Response status is 403`, but the if statement is not true. Looking at the actual response object, it does look like the status is 403 and is an int. My first guess would have been the if statement is evaluating to false due to a different type. its a int not a string? I haven't tried using `==` instead of `===` because my  linter would complain and not transpile. In any case, I'm trying to figure out why this seemingly true statement is evaluating to false.

Comment: Typescript is a compile time check, not a runtime check.  The best way to test your theory on types is to actually log the type.  `console.log(typeof res.stats)`.  And no, using `==` isn't necessarily more correct than parsing if it is in fact a string.

Comment: Good point. Printing typeof res.status shows its a number. The exact log is:
Error status is 403
Type of res.status = number
I have another log inside the if statement but that doesn't get printed

Comment: Sounds like something else is breaking along the way.  Do you have a small plunker that reproduces the issue?  It would make it a lot easier to give additional guidance

Comment: You need to share more of the code that is calling this, etc. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/Response-class.html

Comment: IMHO '==' in this case is good. People seem to stay away from it out of principle while ignoring the cases where it should be used. Ask yourself: if this status code is a string and is '403' do I want this check to be true in that case as well as for numbers? Yes. Yes you do. Because this number does not have identity. It does not have attributes that can change without changing its meaning. I know this is not the cause of the problem but I'd reconfigure my linter if I were you.